# curl fails TLS handshake... sometimes

Tags: curl, ssl

I am trying to download Python 3.6.5 using curl as part of the `pyenv` script to make virtual environments.

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I pinpointed the command at which it fails to this:

```
curl -q -o "Python-3.6.5.tar.xz" -sSLf "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tar.xz"
```

Since the output was still mediocre for me to debug anything, I removed the `-s` (silent), `-S` (only used with `-s`) and `-f` (fail silently), keeping `-L` (makes curl jump location if the server tells it changed location) and adding `-v` (for more verbose output).

Running the command directly on the CLI, this is the result when it fails (80% of the time, more or less):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ curl -q -v -o "Python-3.6.5.tar.xz" -L "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tar.xz"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 2a04:4e42:9::223...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.python.org (2a04:4e42:9::223) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [102 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [3266 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [333 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [70 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.python.org:443
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.python.org:443
```

And this is the result when it is successful:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ curl -q -v -o "test_download.tar.xz" "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tar.xz"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 2a04:4e42:9::223...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.python.org (2a04:4e42:9::223) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [102 bytes data]
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [3266 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [333 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [70 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
{ [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; jurisdictionC=US; jurisdictionST=Delaware; serialNumber=3359300; C=US; ST=New Hampshire; L=Wolfeboro; O=Python Software Foundation; CN=www.python.org
*  start date: Mar 28 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 27 12:00:00 2018 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.python.org" matched cert's "www.python.org"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
} [5 bytes data]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0xe5ee38)
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tar.xz HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.python.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
{ [5 bytes data]
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
} [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/2 200
< server: nginx
< content-type: application/octet-stream
< last-modified: Wed, 28 Mar 2018 10:25:17 GMT
< etag: "5abb6d8d-1042938"
< x-clacks-overhead: GNU Terry Pratchett
< via: 1.1 varnish
< accept-ranges: bytes
< date: Mon, 16 Apr 2018 07:19:46 GMT
< via: 1.1 varnish
< x-served-by: cache-iad2136-IAD, cache-ams4428-AMS
< x-cache: HIT, HIT
< x-cache-hits: 0, 0
< x-timer: S1523863187.771707,VS0,VE4
< strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
< content-length: 17049912
<
{ [2470 bytes data]
  5 16.2M    5  959k    0     0   427k      0  0:00:38  0:00:02  0:00:36  427k^C
```

My internet connection is not very good, 6-7Mbps at most, I have the feeling it could be the culprit behind this, but I'm not well versed enough on TLS and SSL stuff to debug this log.

EDIT:

After running

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo | openssl s_client -connect www.python.org:443
```

This was the output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo | openssl s_client -connect www.python.org:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 businessCategory = Private Organization, jurisdictionC = US, jurisdictionST = Delaware, serialNumber = 3359300, C = US, ST = New Hampshire, L = Wolfeboro, O = Python Software Foundation, CN = www.python.org
verify return:1
write:errno=104
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/businessCategory=Private Organization/jurisdictionC=US/jurisdictionST=Delaware/serialNumber=3359300/C=US/ST=New Hampshire/L=Wolfeboro/O=Python Software Foundation/CN=www.python.org
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/businessCategory=Private Organization/jurisdictionC=US/jurisdictionST=Delaware/serialNumber=3359300/C=US/ST=New Hampshire/L=Wolfeboro/O=Python Software Foundation/CN=www.python.org
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3655 bytes and written 269 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: A764ADBD7183F8912AD3B66A345C6B25398054CC167AE505D3BF9A85E67A9DC41E333BD4A1F0CA280D214588AB21445B
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1523871129
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
```

When I run it the second time, the output is slightly different close to the end:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo | openssl s_client -connect www.python.org:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 businessCategory = Private Organization, jurisdictionC = US, jurisdictionST = Delaware, serialNumber = 3359300, C = US, ST = New Hampshire, L = Wolfeboro, O = Python Software Foundation, CN = www.python.org
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/businessCategory=Private Organization/jurisdictionC=US/jurisdictionST=Delaware/serialNumber=3359300/C=US/ST=New Hampshire/L=Wolfeboro/O=Python Software Foundation/CN=www.python.org
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIH9zCCBt+gAwIBAgIQDEqEI45zRFWbuE0eDzGIgzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADB1
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMTQwMgYDVQQDEytEaWdpQ2VydCBTSEEyIEV4dGVuZGVk
IFZhbGlkYXRpb24gU2VydmVyIENBMB4XDTE4MDMyODAwMDAwMFoXDTE4MDkyNzEy
MDAwMFowgdgxHTAbBgNVBA8MFFByaXZhdGUgT3JnYW5pemF0aW9uMRMwEQYLKwYB
BAGCNzwCAQMTAlVTMRkwFwYLKwYBBAGCNzwCAQITCERlbGF3YXJlMRAwDgYDVQQF
EwczMzU5MzAwMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEWMBQGA1UECBMNTmV3IEhhbXBzaGlyZTES
MBAGA1UEBxMJV29sZmVib3JvMSMwIQYDVQQKExpQeXRob24gU29mdHdhcmUgRm91
bmRhdGlvbjEXMBUGA1UEAxMOd3d3LnB5dGhvbi5vcmcwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB
AQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDB1LZG1YgdWTuFFzVTgBk8HYSupyva2VqB9E3NbGBC
Ys5UPHzAl+aoiV6+by9kTEyFuV6GWOm3Lmtm9MRgCbEyKOC8du4nys2iA7Po24XR
BgZT0dGoLR8b7+DUFwYTaFGFfCsJu+t02buVfeDmfh3DVRtmYvhkSff2/mZLQUDf
bB+AyDauW5jKNpTK3HEAz6VapUxNfFJ5b4dEDS3KwUw28nl7UKny2T92nge9pOtc
HVr1biJEZualZKrdRdf96soss93l2o43Ve3qnS4Bu5obPNq+Sxbr6mlTF2zpZ3Wq
n7NjODIclJIanv6R6JXUP1xYYbzm5NF3K/DcBORuW9fhAgMBAAGjggQdMIIEGTAf
BgNVHSMEGDAWgBQ901Cl1qCt7vNKYApl0yHU+PjWDzAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUaQEj0/XI
KYyyrLVN9NnYEA2n5ZAwggFCBgNVHREEggE5MIIBNYIOd3d3LnB5dGhvbi5vcmeC
D2RvY3MucHl0aG9uLm9yZ4IPYnVncy5weXRob24ub3Jngg93aWtpLnB5dGhvbi5v
cmeCDWhnLnB5dGhvbi5vcmeCD21haWwucHl0aG9uLm9yZ4IPcHlwaS5weXRob24u
b3JnghRwYWNrYWdpbmcucHl0aG9uLm9yZ4IQbG9naW4ucHl0aG9uLm9yZ4ISZGlz
Y3Vzcy5weXRob24ub3Jnggx1cy5weWNvbi5vcmeCB3B5cGkuaW+CDGRvY3MucHlw
aS5pb4IIcHlwaS5vcmeCDWRvY3MucHlwaS5vcmeCD2RvbmF0ZS5weXBpLm9yZ4IT
ZGV2Z3VpZGUucHl0aG9uLm9yZ4ITd3d3LmJ1Z3MucHl0aG9uLm9yZ4IKcHl0aG9u
Lm9yZzAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBaAwHQYDVR0lBBYwFAYIKwYBBQUHAwEGCCsGAQUF
BwMCMHUGA1UdHwRuMGwwNKAyoDCGLmh0dHA6Ly9jcmwzLmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9z
aGEyLWV2LXNlcnZlci1nMi5jcmwwNKAyoDCGLmh0dHA6Ly9jcmw0LmRpZ2ljZXJ0
LmNvbS9zaGEyLWV2LXNlcnZlci1nMi5jcmwwSwYDVR0gBEQwQjA3BglghkgBhv1s
AgEwKjAoBggrBgEFBQcCARYcaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tL0NQUzAH
BgVngQwBATCBiAYIKwYBBQUHAQEEfDB6MCQGCCsGAQUFBzABhhhodHRwOi8vb2Nz
cC5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20wUgYIKwYBBQUHMAKGRmh0dHA6Ly9jYWNlcnRzLmRpZ2lj
ZXJ0LmNvbS9EaWdpQ2VydFNIQTJFeHRlbmRlZFZhbGlkYXRpb25TZXJ2ZXJDQS5j
cnQwDAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADCCAQMGCisGAQQB1nkCBAIEgfQEgfEA7wB2ALvZ37wf
inG1k5Qjl6qSe0c4V5UKq1LoGpCWZDaOHtGFAAABYm2XOKQAAAQDAEcwRQIhAP8A
JukLZLaIMulwFxQHFGoreXVLx397sDgl+XPt8y6oAiBBnYbAzjXczq6hoBuqSkes
YCJ/h5uuNw/tu8OU8csbbQB1AFYUBpov18Ls0/XhvUSyPsdGdrm8mRFcwO+UmFXW
idDdAAABYm2XOKEAAAQDAEYwRAIgJXNv6y7sMRPITc3/ntSX5VIY7RPtq9y1tZhM
adthbjgCICLiyFxrsiRqUUeeBGNvte7YB4VJLhbEnahdkzkmKXBRMA0GCSqGSIb3
DQEBCwUAA4IBAQBawAzb80VNpXwfSiUqxN1QxrV5/dNfrrdnyOHGNwyucSI8k2pK
5VPkSvdCvKn+nSQ3dfpLy8w4kdDW8H4uuO5XwoIBhKyPQSypVe+Rfy7VhNhdwYX/
fhSkmQZCyCRmvkEStJ/gFr0C66INZNXmN+89nsDr+Omqd5U7JPbaJ1xOFFv2uF37
KR/9v04l7k0Ob4KkUj58Ya3Up9risok7hkCcyOtEM9mA9XQ14zhmqOXk+yPL98kB
rgypeNHNsPRv1woG60+M5kRN+yUAuYRS+6EJvvmL74+ZRFjZ1Ww9z/nqopcUpG+3
OVtSWCKzwcEQkezlB5p9dzKIQ/1oiZSAZo39
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/businessCategory=Private Organization/jurisdictionC=US/jurisdictionST=Delaware/serialNumber=3359300/C=US/ST=New Hampshire/L=Wolfeboro/O=Python Software Foundation/CN=www.python.org
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3881 bytes and written 269 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: C64538246CB0B38EBA9A3E9E05D34110CA5A32AE168E6C875989B6FDCFBFA103
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 9D31A94F4E3C2A6FCE02973428F9EB07C38F50A17793760484A97FF89819EE5AE7D859CE06062D63CE8F0C4DBD41B635
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 21 52 ed 0b a1 2a c0 8e-5e 50 a4 07 78 85 ea 05   !R...*..^P..x...
    0010 - 52 6e de 9e cf 11 ac 33-a5 65 03 c7 ad 3f 7e 8f   Rn.....3.e...?~.
    0020 - 09 ca e2 65 3c af 51 41-22 31 07 bd 0e b8 9d 41   ...e<.QA"1.....A
    0030 - 1b be 92 8d fa fd f3 a8-9b 59 73 ea 7c 5e 7e a3   .........Ys.|^~.
    0040 - f0 7d d5 42 7b 34 cc c3-7a 49 fc 08 d7 32 41 69   .}.B{4..zI...2Ai
    0050 - f6 87 b9 dc 7e 7b 66 19-f3 9a d8 2c e5 88 de 95   ....~{f....,....
    0060 - 24 9e 3f 5a 61 4f 5d c5-eb 81 34 80 91 93 bb 45   $.?ZaO]...4....E
    0070 - ad 4a 99 46 de 89 a8 2f-4d 13 a1 89 5c 0c 76 14   .J.F.../M...\.v.
    0080 - 8c 58 5f d2 25 cb ea 84-6a 52 dd 37 70 19 1e c0   .X_.%...jR.7p...
    0090 - d0 b7 40 cf 30 f4 19 a1-74 4d 03 c6 a2 e1 12 85   ..@.0...tM......

    Start Time: 1523871744
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
DONE
```

From what I saw, the first noticeable difference was here, on the first and second times I run the command respectively:

```
SSL handshake has read 3655 bytes and written 269 bytes
SSL handshake has read 3881 bytes and written 269 bytes
```

Comment: Getting `Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.python.org:443` instead of `TLSv1.2` doesn’t give much information to go on. You could try running `echo | openssl s_client -connect www.python.org:443` to see if that’s any more informative (and then [edit] this question if it does show useful details).

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan edited, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Both of those `openssl` commands successfully connected to the remote server. It would be more useful to show the output of an unsuccessful connection. Whenever there's a failure to connect, it would also be useful to ping the IP address, `2a04:4e42:9::223` (I notice you're using IPv6) to check if the failure is at a lower level of the network stack.

Comment: I can only get one message or the other, notice one has `DONE` at the end, the other has not. If I add: `151.101.0.223 www.python.org` to `/etc/hosts` then it always works.

Comment: I didn't notice the `DONE` difference. It's interesting that the `curl -v` shows that command is using IPv6 while adding an IPv4 entry into your `hosts` file guarantees success. I don't (yet) have any experience working with IPv6 or dual-stack systems so I can't really help you. :( The best I can do is upvote your question as you've clearly put a lot of effort into providing relevant information. Welcome to [unix.se] and best of luck finding the answer.

Comment: I'm just a layman in these networking topics, but after searching and asking a friend, I found that I have no default IPv6 DNS configured on my router, maybe that is causing problems? I can't add an IPv6 DNS to my router configs without root user and honestly I don't have the patience to reset all my router setup so that I can create one (that's how it works on mine). After disabling IPv6 on my router and removing the added information on `/etc/hosts` it is working as it should, albeit with an added delay of a couple or more seconds...